# EaselJS: Changing a Shape Objects Dimensions

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

Total noob question. I've been abusing Google and for some reason, have surprisingly not been able to find anything regarding this...? I feel like I'm missing something here. :P

I currently have a resize() function that modifies the canvas dimensions to the size of the window. In a minimal example (which also uses jQuery), I have a variable that references my Shape object. According to the documents, the Shape Object does not include a width & height property. What is the most efficient way of resizing a Shape Object? Removing/redrawing dynamically?

This is what I have:

```
            var stage;

            var bgColor;

            $(document).ready(function(){
                init();
            });

            function init()
            {
                stage = new createjs.Stage("canvasStage");

                bgColor = new createjs.Shape();
                bgColor.graphics.beginFill("#000000").drawRect(0,0, stage.canvas.width, stage.canvas.width);

                stage.addChild(bgColor);

                $(window).resize(function(){windowResize();});
                windowResize();
            }

            function windowResize()
            {
                stage.canvas.width = $(window).width();
                stage.canvas.height = $(window).height();
                //bgColor.width = $(window).height();// No width property
                //bgColor.height = $(window).height();// NO height property

                stage.update();}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the shape's scaleX and scaleY to scale the shape.

Note: The Shape Object extends the DisplayObject so you might also want to look at the DisplayObject docs for many more useful properties/methods.

```
myShape.scaleX=1.2;
myShape.scaleY=1.2;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Kinda sucks that they didn't put width/height properties to objects (I'm getting HTML Table flashbacks). scaleX and scaleY does not serve the same purpose but it looks like this is the only way to do a horizontal/vertical transform.

I ended up using conversion functions, so that I can still accurately use exact width and heights (added to my original post).

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned by @markE, only scaleX and scaleY are available.

A way to work around the problem is to instantiate shapes with 1px width and 1px height:

```
mc_bg = new createjs.Shape();
mc_bg.graphics.beginFill("#CCCCCC").drawRect(0,0,1,1);
stage.addChild(mc_bg);

mc_left = new createjs.Shape();
mc_left.graphics.beginFill("#333333").drawRect(0,0,1,1);
stage.addChild(mc_left);

mc_circle = new createjs.Shape();
mc_circle.graphics.beginFill("#888888").drawCircle(0,0,1,1);
stage.addChild(mc_circle);
```

Allowing to set your dimensions with pixel units without conversion directly by using scaleX and scaleY before rendering:

```
mc_bg.scaleX = stage_width;
mc_bg.scaleY = stage_height;

mc_left.scaleX = stage_width/2;
mc_left.scaleY = stage_height;

mc_circle.x = stage_width/4;
mc_circle.y = stage_width/4;
mc_circle.scaleX = stage_width/4;
mc_circle.scaleY = stage_width/4;

stage.update();
```

See fiddle example with live resizing on window resize: https://jsfiddle.net/jckleinbourg/go3fs1zt/

Answer (score 0):

Conversion methods to change scale --> dimensions and vice versa:

```
function dimToScale(origDim, desiredDim)
{
    return desiredDim / origDim;
}

function scaleToDim(origDim, scale)
{
    return scale * origDim;
}
```